# Log4net in not working in deployed server

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net

I am getting a strange issue in log4net with wcf project. When i run the project locally it is working fine and logging the required log messages in to project. But when I deploy it into server log file is creating but nothing appended into file.

Here is my configurations

```
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
```

And this my section for log4net

```
    <log4net>
    <appender name="EmployeeMovementLog" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="Log\Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %message %newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="EmployeeMovement" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="EmployeeMovementLog" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

I am calling it on application startup

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
```

I have tried every possible alternation before post in here and if anyone faced similar issue and fixed it, please let me know how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There was a error in out core library and i could able to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<logger name="EmployeeMovement" additivity="false">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="EmployeeMovementLog" />
</logger>
```

replace the above code into below

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="EmployeeMovementLog"/>
</root>
```

Comment: It's good practise to have a root element, but it's not required, and this isn't an answer to the question.